# How can I load PDF files directly from Firebase Storage in Android WebView

Tags: android, pdf, android-webview, firebase-storage

I am making an Android App which has a feature that allows users to upload and view PDF files. And for the app, Firebase is the backbone. At the current stage of the app, the PDF files get uploaded to Firebase Storage. But I am having a hard time viewing it. I get the download URL from Firebase and use it in the method: `webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + downloadURL)` But the WebView shows me a grey background with "No Preview Available" written in the centre. I've opened the download URL on my browser and it displays the file perfectly (indicating that the file exists). How can i fix this issue?

Comment: Add your code as to how you are getting the `downloadURL`

Comment: Check my code below for reference

Answer (score 3):

just write one line above

```
 pdf_url=getArguments().getString("pdf_url"); //Ur Firebase Url
    progressBar=view.findViewById(R.id.course_content_progress);

    webView=view.findViewById(R.id.pdfviewr);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }

    });

    String url="";
    try {
        url=URLEncoder.encode(pdf_url,"UTF-8"); //Url Convert to UTF-8 It important.
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webView.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+url);
```

it's work for me.

Happy Coding

Comment: Can you elaborate on the answer? Why did it work for you? :-) This helps users understand your answer.

Comment: I understand What you want. So I did Something Just Checked.